# Only one data listed from xml

Tags: java, android, xml

Database.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
 <staff>
<data1>Hello.jpg</data1>
<data1>World.jpg</data1>
</staff>
```

Class:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeListCountry.getLength(); i++) {

        items.add(elementText.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());

     }
```

** only one data listed**

I'd like to add all xml data in items list collection. But it lists same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having a hard time understanding this question but I am assuming you mean that your items container only has 1 data value in it. This is because you are only adding the first element (element 0) to your items container.

```
 items.add(elementText.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
```

Will only add the first one.

Comment: thanks for your answer but what should i write for getting all the items instead of "item(0)" ?

Comment: First thing you want to do is take the  List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>(); out of the for loop that way its not recreating it every iteration. Have you tried item(i)?

Comment: Might need to be in another for loop or outside the for